# XNA 3D blender models not keeping scale

Tags: c#, xna, models, scaling, blender

So I am making all my models is Blender and then exporting it to .fbx format using the File ->Export and then checking off XNA Strict Options. This works just great, except that when I put my model in XNA, it has been stretched along the up-down axis and it is always the same scale. No matter how much I scale it in Blender, it is always the same size in game. Any ideas? Also, I'm not sure if this is related, but if I have a model with multiple parts, it will only show one part of it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am more familiar with 3ds max than blender, but if this was happening in max I would know what's going on so I'll say it in case Blender works in a similar fashion.

When you modify something in a 3d modeling app (like scaling the model on a particular axis), it does not actually change the positions of the vertices like you may think. It only creates a transform matrix that can be applied to the original vertex positions at render time to make it appear the way you expect.
So when you import the model into Xna, you are importing the model with it's unscaled vertex positions and all the transform matrices it takes to render the model the way you would expect it to. But you have to apply those transforms in your Xna code or the model wont appear the way it did in your modeling app. (the issue you are having)

The way you apply the transforms is by calling the Xna `Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(Matrix[])`. Make sure you **do not call** `Model.CopyBoneTransformsTo(Matrix[])`, you need the one with the word 'Absolute' in it.

Here is a tutorial that shows how to implement that method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203933(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I tried that and it gave me a little trouble. The sphere was on its side, and the view was all messed up. If you could take a look at the code I have and see if I have any thing that might make a difference, that would be great! Thanks a lot! The link is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8lzynqtfs9x7ksw/3d%20test.txt

Comment: you are rendering both 2d items (via spritebatch) and 3d item (models). Calling spritebatch will affect renderstates that have to be reset properly before 3d rendering works correctly. see this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much! I have been trying to get that to work for some time now, and I don't think I would have found that.